# Neural Network (FFW, BP) - function approximation

Tags: neural-network, approximation

is it possible to train NN to approximate this function:
[image: Function]

If I tun approximation for x^2 or sin or something simple, it works fine, but for this sort of function i got only constant valued line.
My NN has 2 inputs (x, f(x)), one hidden layer (10 neurons), 1 output (f(x))
For training I am using BP, activation functions sigmoid -> tanh

My goal is to get "smooth" function without noise, that catch function on image above.

Or is there any other way with NN or genetic algorithm, how to approximate this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gping to have major problems because the input (x, f(x)) is discontinuous (not exactly, but sort of).

Therefore, your NN will have to literally memorize the x-f(x) mapping given the large discontinuities.

One approach is to use a four-layer NN which can address the discontinuities.

But really, you may simply want to look at other smoothening methods rather than NN for thos problem.

You have a periodic function so first of all, only use one period, or you will memorize and not generalize.

Comment: I am using only 1. period for training. Four-layer NN means: 1 input, 3 hidden, 1 output or 4 hidden and 1 output ?

Comment: You will have to test many architectures, start with one hidden layer and a low number of neurons. Then you should increase the number of neurons and the number of layers step for step. Maybe it is even possible to learn the whole function with sine or cosine activation functions.

Comment: Instead of brute force testing, use the well-characterized Cascade Correlation Algorithm.

Comment: Yes, four layer means two sets of hidden layers.  Same equations though.

Comment: A four layer network is theoretically capable of approximating any functionX discontinuous or not.

Comment: Ok thanks.. I will give it a try... but I have to rewrite my NN code first :)

Comment: Ok... I tried it... but result is still more or less constant line. There are 2 possibilities: a) my NN implementation is wrong (but for x^2 and other simple functions it works), b) function is too complex to learn (but result in line is wrong, I would expect at leas some kind of wave)

Comment: The "inductive bias" of a neural network is smooth interpolation between data points.  For the particular function you have, it is very choppy, and interpolation wouldn't work.  I would try approaches such as polynomial fitting, or splines.

Comment: Problem is, that I have different functions. This one, includes in first post, is just an example. And I need something universal. I already tried splines, but they are not good with spikes and need a lot of points, so at the end it was almost better to store original data. Very often I have only monotonic function, which is almost linear. I thought for this problem NN could be good

Comment: Function example: http://www.perry.cz/files/almost-linear.png. Aproximating with only linear function gives more incorrect result with increasing distance from [0,0]

Comment: Try fourier series, or wavelet decomposition.  I think you will get better results.